# border-box is still adding the border to the height of the element

Tags: css, border-box

I have a link-button that has a height of 34px instead of 32px, if box-sizing: border-box would work. And I don't know why.

There is a block element of 24px x 24px
A padding of 4px (top & bottom)
24 + 8 = 32px
But the border adds the other 2px ...

What do I do wrong or forget to add here?

HTML:

```
<div class="link-button">
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span>Inspect me, my height is 34px instead of 32px?</span>
</div>

.link-button{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  min-height: 32px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  color: #267ace;
  background: rgba(38, 122, 206, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block{
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` means the paddings and borders would get subtracted from the `height` you specified. But wait - where _did_ you actually specify the height? You didn't. You specified `min-height: 32px; height: auto;` only.

Comment: @CBroe box-sizing apply to min-height as well (because in the end, min-height will be used to calculate the height). The issue is the content inside that is bigger than the min-height specified. Without that content, the height will be 32px as the OP expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logic is correct and the height should be equal to `32px` but don't forget that you have content inside having a height equal to `24px`. You specified a `min-height` and not `height` so your element is allowed to expand if the content doesn't fit inside.

```
24px of content height + 2x4px padding + 2x1px border = 34px
```

`34px` is bigger than `32px` so you will end with a height equal to `34px`

Seen differently, you content height should be equal to:

```
32px - 2x4px padding - 2x1px border = 22px
```

`22px` are not enough to hold your `24px` (the height of the content) so `2px` are added to the content height and you get `34px`

---

It's a coincidence that the added height is equal to the border but it's not related. Add more content inside and the height will keep growing

```css
.link-button{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  min-height: 32px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  color: #267ace;
  background: rgba(38, 122, 206, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block{
  width: 24px;
  height: 26px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-button">
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span>Inspect me, my height is 36px instead of 32px?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do know it grows when the content grows. 
But I want to keep it exactly as my design off course.

I use a min-height, because I want the link-button to have the same height when there is no icon (.block)

I'm not using height because the text can fall on a second line.

I think the only solution to this is using outline instead of border.